# A complete list of unsafe string handling functions and their safer replacements for linux

Tags: linux, string, unsafe

I am looking for something like that:

strcpy -> strncpy

sprintf -> snprintf

etc

Google does not know I a'm afraid. Do you?

Comment: Usually when you lookup the man pages on the function it gives you a list of alternatives so if you ever have any doubt just open up the man page and you can see all the alternate versions of the function (which may be what you're looking for) that are not as easy to cause buffer overflows in

Comment: You can search ANSI C standard document, and see 7.21 String handling <string.h>.

Comment: `gets()` -> `fgets()`, that's the only function that is _always_ unsafe

Answer (score 2):

- strcpy -> strncpy -> strlcpy/strcpy_s
- strcat -> strncat -> strlcat/strcat_s
- strtok
- sprintf -> snprintf
- vsprintf -> vsnprintf
- gets -> fgets/gets_s
- makepath -> _makepath_s (MSDN)
- _splitpath -> _splitpath_s (MSDN)
- scanf/sscanf -> sscanf_s (MSDN)
- snscanf -> _snscanf_s (MSDN)
- strlen -> strnlen_s (MSDN) / [strnlen](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strnlen.3.html)

MSDN has a article covering banned functions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288454.aspx